# Tela branca na inicialização IOS

Tags: ionic, ionic3

Estou desenvolvendo um app com o Ionic na versão 3 mas estou tendo um problema com o build pra IOS, apenas para IOS.

Por vários dias pesquisei e não encontrei uma solução para meu problema, conseguir compilar as últimas duas versões sem problema, mas agora que estou precisando lançar outra versão, não está indo nem a PAUU!!

> Apenas o build para IOS está dando problema.

### O problema

Depois do build testando em um dispositivo real, o aplicativo entra na splashscreen e sai, entrando em uma tela branca que não sai de jeito nenhum.

Isto ocorre apenas no build com a flag `--prod`. Quando eu rodo em modo *debug* funciona perfeitamente, com livereload e tudo mais.

#### Informações

No console do XCode a única coisa que vejo é toda inicialização e quando o app está travado na tela branca vejo `TIC Read Status [10:0x0]: 1:57` e `TIC Read Status [11:0x0]: 1:57`

Será bem-vinda qualquer tentativa de ajuda. Obrigado desde já!

Answer (score -1):

Na página do Ionic, há uma explicação que informa que uma das causas pode ser a instalação incorreta da plataforma.

https://ionicframework.com/docs/wkwebview/

Se o problema for esse, a orientação para correção é a seguinte:

- Feche o Xcode
- Remova plataformas e plugins

  `rm -rf platforms`

  `rm -rf plugins`
- Inclua a plataforma novamente

  `ionic cordova platform add ios`
- Certifique-se de que a navegação para o localhost está permitida:

  `<allow-navigation href="http://localhost:8080/*"/>`
- Certifique-se de que o WKWebView é o padrão:

  `<feature name="CDVWKWebViewEngine">
     <param name="ios-package" value="CDVWKWebViewEngine" />
  </feature>
  <preference name="CordovaWebViewEngine" value="CDVWKWebViewEngine" />`
- Faça o build novamente

  `ionic cordova build ios`